# Stock price changes by 10% instantly between AH close and premarket open?

Tags: stock-markets

Can someone explain what happened here?

[image: chart1]

It appears that the stock price fell by nearly 10% between the time the AH market closed at 19:59 and the time it opened again at 06:00

How is this possible? The volume for those two ticks were only 164 and 100, respectively, whereas the nearby candles have much higher volume and do not move the price hardly at all. The next highest volume candle is 1300 and only moves the price $0.82 cents

[image: chart2]

I thought volume dictates the amount the price changes? How does the stock price change so drastically on so little volume during the seconds between the extended close/open?

Comment: How much real time passed between the price changes?  Markets are moving wildly right now so even if it was a few hours I wouldn't be surprised by a 10% change in that time.  The market doesn't need to be open for people's estimate of the price to change.  If the market was closed overnight and someone announced that they discovered cold fusion before it opened then every energy stock would be crushed when the market did open.

Comment: @RWP 8pm to 6am ET... So are there other markets trading this stock during that time? Because if not, then whats driving the price change if there are no sales going on?

Comment: @cds333 Whether or not the stock is traded, the fundamental realities of the business can change. If a Boeing airplane crashes on Sunday night, and a news report says that its because of faulty programming, hasn't the true value of Boeing dropped, whether or not anyone has traded it yet?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon ok, but one need only visit stocktwits to see that there are always people bullish on SOXL, no matter what day or time. There's always some guy willing to pay market price. I find it hard to believe that not a single person would pay over $70/share on a popular stock that closed at $80.

Comment: @cds333 Have you not noticed what happened in the last week? Market realities can change very quickly. Turns out not a single person would pay over $70 on this particular stock that closed at $80. You're looking at one of the worst stock crashes in market history, so this is not a common thing, but it clearly isn't impossible, either.

Answer (score 1):

The price of a stock [or the cumulative price of many stocks, which form the overall price of an index] is based purely on the latest price change.

If I own shares in an airline, and that airline shuts down operations due to, say, a global pandemic, I will no longer expect to receive the 'old price' when selling them. So I will lower my expectations. Likewise buyers will not offer the 'old price', they will only be willing to pay a lower amount.

When a single trade happens at the new price, that becomes the price, period.

Usually high volumes of trades are needed to shift price, without abnormal events shifting expected value of the shares. So if 1,000 shares are on offer for $100, and 500 shares on offer for $101, then 1,000 shares would need to be bought before the $101 price is the lowest available price, and then another 500 shares would need to be sold before the price rises again.

**It seems you are using an attempt at 'technical analysis' to determine how to 'time' the market. This is incredibly risky**.  I would further caution you to never invest in something you do not fully understand - asking questions like this is a great way to increase your understanding, but always be sure to ask such questions *before* you put your money at risk, and not after.

Comment: I made no attempt to time anything. I simply asked why the opening price wasn't closer to the closing price.

Comment: This does not explain why the opening price is not the same as the closing price. What happened between the time the market closed at 8pm and the time the market opened at 6am that changed the price so drastically? Are there foreign markets trading during that time?

Comment: "When a single trade happens at the new price, that becomes the price, period." - So you are saying one guy bought 100 shares at 6am precisely, from a guy who put them up for sale at $70 the previous night, when the share price was $80?

Comment: @cds333 they would not have left the price in over night.  Both the buy and sell step would have happened that morning.

Comment: Yep, don't try to time the market.  It's "time in the market". Etc. Etc.  Well, until it's time out of the market which is now (unless you're hedged).

Comment: @cds333 Someone put an order in before the market opened to sell, and someone put an order in to buy. Those orders were matched immediately once the market opened.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon So if that's all it takes to drop the stock price 10% why couldn't my buddy put up a few shares for sale at $1, then I buy them, then that causes the price to drop, and I buy up a few thousand more from some unwitting guy who put in a "sell at market value" order?

Comment: @cds333 There are two sets of order books (think about it like to lines of people entering an auction house): buyers and sellers. Every buyer lines up in order from the highest bid price to the lowest bid price - the highest bid price is basically the one 'facing' the line of sellers, because his/her bid will be viewed first. Every seller lines up in order from the lowest ask price to the highest ask price - the lowest ask price is basically the one 'facing' the line of buyers. All offers that have already been matched are out of the room...

Comment: And the last real, market-price trade was, say, $90. The highest bidder left is, say, $89, and behind him/her there are dozens/hundreds/tens of thousands of buyers willing to pay something less than $89. There is still a seller willing to accept $90 for his/her stock, and behind him/her there are however many sellers willing to take $91 or more for their own stocks. Now your buddy bursts into the room, offering to sell his shares for $1. Imagine he does this in a room of 10,000 waiting to trade. After someone gives him $1, the line of sellers remains the same, and the line of buyers remains.

Comment: So your plan fails, because you aren't convincing anyone the value of the shares has dropped. The 'market price' is just the last transacted price, but that doesn't mean people will automatically trade at that price. That's why there is still an order book of buyers and an order book of sellers who will only buy / sell at a price they pre-determined: because they believe the stock is worth a (slightly) different amount.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Thank you for explaining that. It makes much more sense now.